# Energy Consumption tool and CPU Sampling in Visual Studio 2013 is coming as non applicable tool. How to enable it?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

[image: I have my csharp .Net solution opened in VS2013 and i want to do performance testing of my project in VS2013 with its new feature performance and Diagnostics but "Energy Consumption tool" is disabled. How to enable it?]
I have my csharp .Net solution opened in VS2013 and i want to do performance testing of my project in VS2013 with its new feature performance and Diagnostics but "Energy Consumption tool" is disabled. How to enable it?

Answer (score 0):

CPU Usage tool and Energy Consumption tool are not available on Windows 7. Try to use them on a machine with Windows 8.1.

Comment: same problem happens to me on Windows 10